# identifying unique values of a grouped variable

Tags: r, tidyverse

I am trying to count the # of unique date values across multiple visits. Here is sample data:

```
id    date     
1     2017-08-31
1     2017-08-31
1     2017-05-06
2     2015-09-01
2     2015-11-01
3     2010-12-02
3     2010-12-02
```

I want a df that shows how many unique dates there are per participant. Something like this:

```
id    total_visit
1       2
2       2 
3       1
```

I tried this code, but it's not doing what I want it to do.

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 <- df %>% group_by(id) %>% count(distinct(date))
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: Use summarise()

Comment: Use `df %>% group_by(id) %>% summarize(total_visit=n_distinct(date))`